# Arrange images in a radial stack, and manipulate overlap manually

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am using a stack to arrange images in a circle, with slight overlap. But I want the green icon to overlap the grey icon, while maintaining the other overlapping order. Basically I want each icon to be only partially obscured. Please see attached image and code.

[image: stack]

```
Stack(
  children: [
    Positioned(
      bottom: 3,
      left: 0,
      child: SvgPicture.asset(
        'images/elem_earth.svg',
        width: 15,
      ),
    ),
    Positioned(
      top: 3,
      left: 0,
      child: SvgPicture.asset(
        'images/elem_dark.svg',
        width: 15,
      ),
    ),
    Positioned(
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      child: SvgPicture.asset(
        'images/elem_light.svg',
        width: 15,
      ),
    ),
    Positioned(
      top: 3,
      right: 0,
      child: SvgPicture.asset(
        'images/elem_fire.svg',
        width: 15,
      ),
    ),
    Positioned(
      bottom: 3,
      right: 0,
      child: SvgPicture.asset(
        'images/elem_ice.svg',
        width: 15,
      ),
    ),
    Positioned(
      bottom: 0,
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      child: SvgPicture.asset(
        'images/elem_air.svg',
        width: 15,
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```